# htaccess Rewrite rule appending query string parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a rewrite rule for below URLs: redirect

- `www.domain.com/mbc-ex` to `www.domain.com`
- `www.domain.com/mbc-ex?abcd=123`  to `www.domain.com`

Basically, I do not want to have any query string parameters after redirection. Here is the rule I tried

```
^/mbc-ex\?(.*)$  http://www.domain.com [NC,L,U]
```

the above rule still appends the query string parameters

```
^/mbc-ex$ http://www.domain.com [NC,L,U]
```

this one works as expected

Comment: `RewriteRule` does NOT work with query string directly -- only with path part of the URL. To match query string use `RewriteCond`.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your regex is not matching at all.

```
^/mbc-ex\?(.*)$ http://www.domain.com  [NC,L,U]
```

According to the examples at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html, you do not need to use the backslash on the question mark.

Here's a handy online test tool for checking your rules: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Using that I was able to get your url to work properly using the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^mbc-ex/?(.*) http://www.domain.com [NC,L,U]
```

Comment: I tried that it redirects me to http://www.domain.com/mbc-ex?abcd=123. but the page content is loaded correctly

Comment: Shouldn't it be redirecting to www.domain.com?

Comment: sorry!. you are right. I typed it wrong , it is redirecting me to www.domain.com/mbc-ex?abcd=123

Answer (score 0):

You need the QSD|qsdiscard flag

```
^/mbc-ex  http://www.domain.com [NC,L,U,QSD]
```

Since apache2 2.4.0

Pre 2.4.0: Add a ? to the end of you new url

```
^/mbc-ex  http://www.domain.com? [NC,L,U]
```